# Why is the doctor's holographic projection tangible sometimes and intangible at other times?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In "Future's end, part 2", the doctor is fired upon by two Earth militants and the bullets pass through his holographic matrix. Only two scenes prior, with his new holographic projector, he receives and gives punches with starlings associate. How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is directly explained in VOY S1E5, "[Phage](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phage_(episode))." The Doctor's body is composed of photons contained within a forcefield, and he can "modulate" the forcefield **at will** to either collide with solid matter or pass through it.

> PARIS: But a hologram is just a projection of light held in a magnetic containment field. There's no real matter involved.
>
> (The EMH slaps Paris.)
>
> EMH: Now, you hit me.
>
> (Paris's hand passes through the EMH's head.)
>
> EMH: The magnetic containment field that creates the illusion of my body can be modulated to allow matter to pass through it or be stopped.

Comment: I've bolded 'at will' since it's important to note that he doesn't need to do anything visible to change it.

Comment: How does he affect the containment field at will?

Comment: @HamSandwich Presumably the same way he controls the containment field's shape and position when walking.